# Post parameter is null when posting to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman

I am using the following controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CoreLog([FromBody]PAV model)
{
   //Process model
}
```

When running a local instance of my ASP.net web app in VS and posting to http://localhost:53270/api/bundle/Corelog the CoreLog controller method is receiving a populated model which is correct.

However, when publishing the web app to a server (Windows Server 2012 R2) and hosting via ISS, posting the same message (even when posting to the local host on the server itself) always results in the model being null once received.

I am ensuring the `content-type` is set to `application/json` when posting via Postman.

What could be causing this?

Model:

```
public class PAV
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string eID { get; set; }
}
```

Posted JSON:

```
{ 
   "Name":"Test",
   "eID":"12345" 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting your posted JSON to include the variable name i.e `{ "model": { "Name": "Test", "eID": "12345" } }`. You shouldn't need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, you need to add [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to PAV entity

```
 [DataContract]
 public class PAV
 {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string eID { get; set; }
 }
```

Please find the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).

Comment: That worked! Posting to the server is now working as expected. Thanks!